# Disable radio input using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want the radio input disabled by default. But its not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('input').attr('disabled', true);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="harvest" id="first"> First
</form>
```

I tried the following also:

```
    $('input[type=radio]').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#first').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Your code, as provided [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/6k2hue7s/) please [edit] and click `[<>]` to create a snippet and all the relevant code to *demonstrate* the issue.  Have a read of [How to create a snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?  eg $ not defined?

Comment: You can also add the `disabled` attribute to the html markup as a backup so it's disabled by default. `<input type="radio" name="harvest" id="first" disabled>`  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name=harvest]').prop('disabled', true);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
        <input type="radio" name="harvest" id="first"> First
    </form>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.  See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Only 1 issue on you jQuery code, didn't close properly. Use specific ID $('#first') or class to refer the input field you want to disable. Using $('input') will disable all the input field.
For more details please check https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('input').attr('disabled', true);
    } ); /* Didn't close properly on your code*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="harvest" id="first"> First
</form>
```